# How to get supportactionbar when my class extends ExpandableListActivity

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-support-library, android-actionbar-compat

I have a class which extends `ExpandableListActivity` to display my data as explandable list view, now my app supporting older version till API 7 how to add `ActionBar` using `getSupportActionBar()` to this class...Please help me out

```
public class Facts extends ExpandableListActivity {


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    try{
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.facts);

        SimpleExpandableListAdapter expListAdapter =
                new SimpleExpandableListAdapter(
                        this,
                        createGroupList(),              // Creating group List.
                        R.layout.facts_grouprow,                // Group item layout XML.
                        new String[] { "questions" },   // the key of group item.
                        new int[] { R.id.row_name },    // ID of each group item.-Data under the key goes into this TextView.
                        createChildList(),              // childData describes second-level entries.
                        R.layout.facts_childrow,                // Layout for sub-level entries(second level).
                        new String[] {"answers"},       // Keys in childData maps to display.
                        new int[] { R.id.grp_child}     // Data under the keys above go into these TextViews.
                        );
        setListAdapter(expListAdapter);     // setting the adapter in the list

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Errrr +++ " + e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

now suggest me to how to achieve it.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [ExpandableListActivity source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/app/ExpandableListActivity.java), it seems like it would be easy to duplicate the same functionality in your own class and have it extend `ActionBarActivity` as its base class.

Comment: are you saying that I have to write custom adapter and extend it to BaseExpandableListAdapter to achieve that ha..

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use the [`ActionBarActivity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html). There you have the method [`getSupportActionBar`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html#getSupportActionBar%28%29).

To show your `ExpandableList` you can add a [`ListFragment`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ListFragment.html) from the support-v4 lib.
There is a method called `setListAdapter()` where you can add a [`ExpandableListAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListAdapter.html).

[Here is an example.](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#expandablelistview)

Comment: could you please elaborate to my context of question as I have edited my question,also link provided you as an example doesn't uses list uses List-fragment, It just uses custom-adapter which extends BaseExpandableListAdapter

Comment: I add the example because I didn't know if you already worked with `Fragments`. You also can add your `SimpleExpandableListAdapter` to the `setListAdapter`, so you don't have to write a custom `ExpandableListAdapter`.

Comment: Correct me if I interpreting you wrong..you are saying that my `Facts` class should extend `ActionBarActivity`, from it call a fragment which extends `ListFragment`, in that `ListFragment` I can use `SimpleExpandableListAdapter` to the `setListAdapter`

Comment: ok @owe let me do this and accept your answer if works fine...thanks for suggesting me