# how to create a actionbar for list and i am using TabLayout for creating a list

Tags: android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!-- PARENT -->
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:stretchColumns="1" android:paddingTop="0dip"     android:layout_gravity="top"
>

<TableRow>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="50dip"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"/>
    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:stretchColumns="1" android:paddingTop="0dip" android:layout_gravity="top"
        >
        <TableRow>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text1"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:textSize="17dip" android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="25dip"
        android:id="@+id/DownArrow"
        android:layout_height="25dip"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:background="@drawable/downimage"
        />

</TableRow>
```

how can i set action bar?in java class i used "public class ExpandableListMain extends ExpandableListActivity".  here i am not used extends ActionBarActivity or Activity, and also i tried this one also,i create a separate a layout for action bar and i insert this xml code,it creates separate action bar for each and every list

Comment: Use a Toolbar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31231609/creating-a-button-in-android-toolbar

Comment: Thanks for your Reply

Answer (score 0):

Go through [ExpandableListActivity](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/app/ExpandableListActivity.java) , it is easy to use ActionBarActivity as base class and having same functionality as extending ExpandableListActivity

It would be easy to get the same functionality in your own class and have it extend ActionBarActivity as its base class.

Check this [Stack description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22007024/how-to-get-supportactionbar-when-my-class-extends-expandablelistactivity)

Comment: Thanks for your Reply

Comment: Sir i already used ExpandableListActivity in my java file,but  i cant get correct result. i create separate layout for actionbar,when i insert the layout into above TabLayout xml it doesnot work...separate actionbar will created for each members present in the list.

Comment: please refer link describe in my answer it will help you to solve your issue @SivashankariMoorthy